# How to install nginx,php and laravel on centos6.9?

Tags: nginx, centos, vps

I have purchased godaddy vps server and on that I want to install nginx,laravel and php.

I was trying to install nginx I am getting issue:

```
nginx: [alert] could not open error log file: open() "/var/log/nginx/error.log" failed (2: No such file or directory)

 1. List item

2017/11/21 03:52:00 [emerg] 23590#0: open() "/etc/nginx/nginx.conf" failed (2: No such file or directory)
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check if SELinux is off.

**Updated:**
Please disable SELinux as guide here:
https://www.tecmint.com/disable-selinux-temporarily-permanently-in-centos-rhel-fedora/

To save your time, please try below command:
    **setenforce 0**
Then try your work again.

Comment: where is this option?could you please explain?